# Data singular or plural in the context of particular input data?

Tags: grammatical-number

We have a paper about a novel statistical model and we describe its input data. Should we write

> The input data also **include** a vector of numbers F ...

or

> The input data also **includes** a vector of numbers F ...

?

Google search tells me that:

> data is treated as singular when used as a mass noun to mean
> “information” and as plural when used to mean “individual facts.”

I don't think our context is mass noun, but it is not "individual facts" either. I would be inclined to use it as plural, sounds more natural to me, but colleague has similar feeling about the singular. Which one is correct?

Comment: IMO data is almost always singular in most writing. I don't know about statistics, which may have a completely different convention, but in general English "data includes" generally feels more natural today. Maybe ask on a statistics forum if you are specifically worried about the usage in the field of statistics. If you search here for *data singular* you will find a lot of relevant questions, but as I said, statisticians may not follow the same conventions.

Comment: This is almost certainly opinion-based: neither usage is incorrect per se. 'I don't think our context is a mass noun' indicates a misunderstanding; you can _choose_ the count (which takes a plural form verb, as the word is plural in form) or noncount (which always takes a singular verb form, like the majority of noncount usages) usage. And while the noncount usage is, as Stuart says, far more common in general, some academics prefer ... even insist on ... the count usage when used in their domain (eg stats). // Choosing 'the data include' emphasises individual items of data.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks (and to Sturat as well). With "The input data" I mean a very specific and well defined "package" of all the data that the model takes at the input. And I am saying that this one package also contains this specific thing. But I am not sure if this usage makes the "input data" a plural or singular.

Comment: As I said, there is no basic rule dictating this. (There may well be pressure from others of a more prescriptivist bent, and the choice may well be affected by seeking to accommodate the intended audience.) But neither should be considered ungrammatical.

Comment: This also differs between American and British English. I think Brits treat it as plural rather than a mass noun.

Comment: *Include* creates the image of *input data* as a container of the vector. This is a notionally singular usage driven by the particular choice of verb. But you could also have " the input data comprise several vector elements", where the verb creates a pairing between input data and the input fields. I was under the impression that you'd normally just use *input* as the collective noun.